# Printing out array of random numbers in C

Tags: c, arrays, random, numbers

just trying to create a 8 x 8 array, and print it out, but it only prints out a single "1" every time. Help is much appreciated!

```
void main()
{
    int i = 0, j = 0, array[8][8];
    for (i=0; i<10; ++i);   
    {
        for (j=0; j<10; ++j);
        {
            array[i][j] =  ;
            printf("%d ", array[i][j]);
        }
    printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: `void main` is wrong. `main` returns `int`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the semi-colons from the end of your `for` statements - otherwise they do nothing.

Comment: loooool just realized. Was at it for hours like this has to work haha thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You forgot ; at the end of your `for`s

Because of that, your for doesn't do anything, and you only fill and print ten_by_ten[10][10].

You should compile your programs with the -Wall flag, and carefully read what is printed, I guess such behavior would have been signaled.